# comparison of two numbers in python in if condition does not work correctly, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, if-statement

I have part of code that compares two numbers in python,

```
   if (vw_q==vw_q):
        if dst<=th:
            cnd= not cnd
            print vw_d,vw_q,dst
    matched_index[j]=cnd
```

and the condition (first if) compares two numbers if thwo numbers are equal go to the next if condition, however, the output is not correct. This is first few outputs:

```
24 38 44.929686067367584
20 14 22.70541826128124
10 11 35.3443227053815
24 44 1.650238537037012
39 42 11.848092479431216
39 28 11.848092479431216
23 46 0.18987032267705217
23 15 0.18987032267705217
.
.
.
```

Do you have point about this, why?

Comment: When would you expect `vw_q != vw_q`? Also note that your code isn't consistent in use of whitespace, parentheses, etc.; I'd recommend following [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) as a baseline.

Comment: Don't edit the mistake out of your question. The question wouldn't make sense any more.

Comment: In general, your code is full of terrible variable names: vw_q, vw_d, dst, th, cnd, j. This causes many problems, but in particular here you probably wouldn't have made this mistake if you had longer names that don't differ by only 1 letter. Use proper, meaningful names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing the first number to itself in the first if statement.

Change it to:

```
 if (vw_d==vw_q):
    if dst<=th:
        cnd= not cnd
        print vw_d,vw_q,dst
matched_index[j]=cnd
```

You should spend some time trying to work out errors yourself before posting on here, as this one is something you could definitely have resolved yourself.

Comment: I am really sorry, I think I am so tired to do this silly mistakes, Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @S.EB No worries. Everyone makes these mistakes sometimes. Try to be more thorough with proofreading before posting on here next time. If my answer was suitable, please give it a tick as well. Cheers!